# Link between the FDA and LS-SVM

Tags: svm, discriminant-analysis

I am reading tutorial written by Johan Suykens:`Least Squares Support Vector Machines`

On page 19,he mentions link with kernel Fisher Discriminant Analysis
Project data from the original input space to one dimensional variable.
I do not understand this,can someone elaborate more on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The linear discriminant function by definition is a linear combination of the original input space $d(x) = w^Tx$. You do classification on the projected data $d(x)$ which is 1 dimensional (you project the data on a line).